# Police Data Api Problems

Tags: javascript, api

Basically i'm a noob and just need a starting point. Can you see what's wrong with my code?

```
$.getJSON('http://data.police.uk/api/crime-categories', function(json) {
alert(json.url.name);
});
```

as you can see I just want to get categories and print them out to the page.

link to jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ZfvKm/2852/

Comment: You're not making a JSONP request, you're making a standard AJAX request, so you can see in your error console that the request is being rejected because it's cross-domain. The API may not even support JSONP.

Comment: Thank you. Just tried it in PHP and got a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser is preventing your AJAX call from retrieving this data due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  Basically, this means that your JavaScript code can only retrieve URLs which are at the same host (www.example.com), protocol (http or https), and port (80, 8080, etc..) as the page that is hosting the script.

Since it appears that this API does not support [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), you'll have to retrieve this through your server side code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does that mean I cannot use JavaScript to get the data? Should I use PHP curl request?