# Empty API Page - R

Tags: r

I have a simple API that doesn't even display in my web browser.

https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-at-location?date=2017-02&location_id=884227

Others seem to have my issue ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226492/police-data-api-problems) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384897/php-police-api-not-returning-a-result)), but as a newbie, I still don't fully understand what the issue is, especially in the context of R.

The first post seems to suggest that there's an issue with 'same origin policy', while in the second post, the issue seems to be the way the url is read in.

How can I diagnose the issue to figure out where the problem is, and in R, how could I actually parse such an API?

My current code is below, but it returns empty, just as in my browser:

```
api <- "https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-at-location?date=2017-02&location_id=884227"

r <- GET(api)
json_as_text <- content(r, "text")
json <- fromJSON(json_as_text)
df <- json %>% as_tibble()
df
```

Comment: I pasted the url into my firefox browser, enabled the dev-console (for me, `F12`), and then load the page. The first network attempt fails with HTTP [`500`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) return status, indicating an internal server error. It could be for many reasons. That's their sample URL, and that query as well as their [lat/lon-based query](https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-at-location?date=2017-02&lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592) both fail, suggesting their API is down.

Comment: In the case of your code, you should always check the return status of your queries, to ignore it is bad practice in programming. See that `r$status_code` is `500`, which refers to the HTTP error 500, which a web search will reveal is as I suggested above: an internal server error, which could be anything but is likely a problem with the remote end.

Comment: Ahhh thank  you for the insights, especially the point about checking the status code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that their example code assumes dates that are not available.

Reading into their API docs, one endpoint is [*Availability*](https://data.police.uk/docs/method/crimes-street-dates/):

```r
r <- httr::GET("https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street-dates")
r$status_code
# [1] 200        # good, this is normal
sapply(httr::content(r, type="application/json"), `[[`, "date")
#  [1] "2021-11" "2021-10" "2021-09" "2021-08" "2021-07" "2021-06" "2021-05" "2021-04" "2021-03" "2021-02" "2021-01" "2020-12"
# [13] "2020-11" "2020-10" "2020-09" "2020-08" "2020-07" "2020-06" "2020-05" "2020-04" "2020-03" "2020-02" "2020-01" "2019-12"
# [25] "2019-11" "2019-10" "2019-09" "2019-08" "2019-07" "2019-06" "2019-05" "2019-04" "2019-03" "2019-02" "2019-01" "2018-12"
```

Perhaps they have "expired" old data, or for whatever reason they can no longer return it. If we adapt your initial query to be more recent than `"2018-12"` (inclusive), then we indeed see data:

```r
r <- httr::GET("https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-at-location?date=2018-12&location_id=884227")
r$status_code
# [1] 200
str(httr::content(r, type="application/json"))
# List of 1
#  $ :List of 9
#   ..$ category        : chr "shoplifting"
#   ..$ location_type   : chr "Force"
#   ..$ location        :List of 3
#   .. ..$ latitude : chr "52.643950"
#   .. ..$ street   :List of 2
#   .. .. ..$ id  : int 884227
#   .. .. ..$ name: chr "On or near Abbey Gate"
#   .. ..$ longitude: chr "-1.143042"
#   ..$ context         : chr ""
#   ..$ outcome_status  :List of 2
#   .. ..$ category: chr "Investigation complete; no suspect identified"
#   .. ..$ date    : chr "2018-12"
#   ..$ persistent_id   : chr "d2fc26387d5fee5763d675272385868fced641579788665dcadf37fa782c3278"
#   ..$ id              : int 70623600
#   ..$ location_subtype: chr ""
#   ..$ month           : chr "2018-12"
```

To me, the 500 is a bit misleading: while I understand that the API internal code likely hit an error condition, it also seems likely that this error condition (no data found) could have resulted in something more meaningful, such as one of several other [HTTP error codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), or perhaps just an empty return (json empty dictionary `{}`, or just nothing).

Comment: Ahhhh I feel so silly for missing this, thank you so much for helping!

Comment: You won't forget the next time :-)